# using find command in unix to search for a newline

Tags: linux, unix

I would like to search all .java files which have the newline escape sequence `\n` (backslash followed by 'n') in the files.

I am using this command:

```
find . –name "*.java" –print | xargs grep “\n”
```

but the result shows all lines in .java files having the letter **n**. 
I want to search for a newline `\n`.

Can you please suggest a solution?

Example:

```
x.java
method abc{
String msg="\n Action not allowed.";}

y. java
method getMsg(){
String errMsg = "\n get is not allowed.";}
```

---

I want to search all *.java files having these type of strings defined with newline escape sequence.

Comment: `\n` is newline; `\r` is carriage return.  What are you after?

Comment: sry i was mistaken i am searching for new line \n

Comment: On Unix systems, every line in every file ends with a newline, by definition.  A line is a sequence of characters terminated by a newline.  Even in a binary file (`.class` file or object file), lines are interpreted as a sequence of characters up to the next newline character (even if there are millions of characters in total, including zero or null bytes).

Comment: @sailaja kasanur which shell you are using.

Comment: i am using tcsh shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to find lines containing the 2-character sequence `\n`. To do this, use `grep -F`, which treats the pattern as a fixed string rather than as a regular expression or escape sequence.

```
find . –name "*.java" –print | xargs grep -F "\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

This -P grep will match a newline character. using '$'.
Since each line in my file contains a newline ,it will match every line.

```
grep -P '$' 1.c
```

I don't know why you want to match a newline character in files.That is strange.

Comment: I have many string messages defined as "\n xxx" in many .java files. These messages will be displayed during exceptions. I want to search all the strings messages which are defined starting with \n

Comment: @sailajakasanur Then you should give us a exact example of the line you want to match.If your newline character is written in "\n".you can use grep -P "\\\n"   e.g: echo "\n xxx"|grep -o -P "\\\n" to match "\n".  sorry i don't use tcsh,don't know if it supports perl regex.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for this:

```
find . –name "*.java" –exec grep -H '"[^"]*\n' {} \;
```

The `-H` flag is to show the name of the file when there was a pattern match. If that doesn't work for you:

```
find . –name "*.java" –print0 | xargs -0 grep '"[^"]*\n'
```

If `xargs -0` doesn't work for you:

```
find . –name "*.java" –print | xargs grep '"[^"]*\n'
```

If `grep` doesn't work for you:

```
find . –name "*.java" –print | xargs egrep '"[^"]*\n'
```

I needed this last version in Solaris, in modern systems the first one should work.

Finally, not sure if the pattern covers all your corner cases.